# Valid anchorStringUnit values

Tags: docusignapi

What reference material does Docusign have so I can see the valid anchorStringUnit values for tabs? I've looked everywhere and am coming up empty handed.

I've looked everywhere, got nothing. All I know is "inches" because they mention that in the one example I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The API Reference](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocumenttabs/create/#schema_201_tabs_tabs_datetabs_anchortabprocessorversionmetadata) has this information:

[image]

So, it appears there are 4 values (pixels, inches, millimeters, and centimeters) that are valid for **AnchorUnits** as you can see above (these are strings).

(the default is pixels, so if you don't specify this value, it will defer to pixels).